# How do i get an object nested in another object using Angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object

I'm consuming an object from an api like this.

[image: Object]

I can get the data but cant get the ChildSimpleProducts Array exclusively.

here is the product.service function

```
  getProducts = (): Observable<IProducts[]> => this.http.get<IProducts[]>(`${this.apiUrl + this.productsUrl}`);
```

and here is the component function

```
  data: any = [];


productsArray: Observable<IProducts>[];
getProducts() {
this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(data => {
  this.data = data;
  this.productsArray = data["$values"];
  console.log(this.productsArray)
})
```

}

i have tried a few things but keep getting undefined and undefined objects

Comment: Did u try this.productsArray[0].childSimpleProducts?

Comment: Did u try data.$values;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use forEach to loop through all the productsArray and get the childSimpleProducts,

```
getProducts() {
 this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(data => {
  this.data = data;
  this.productsArray = data["$values"];
  this.productsArray.forEach( e => console.log(e.childSimpleProducts);
  //this.productsArray.filter( e => e.childSimpleProducts); // This will return you an array of childSimpleProducts
 })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If u get data from api correctly then  `data.$values` return result

```
data: any = [];
productsArray: Observable<IProducts>[];
getProducts() {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
      this.productsArray = data.$values;
      console.log(this.productsArray)
      this.productsArray.forEach(x=>{
          console.log(x.ChildSimpleProducts)
      })
    })
 }
```

Comment: **@Çağrı,  that part is already working, so i'm logging the the object but i want to get the child products exclusively and store them in a separate variable**

Comment: Ahh sorry I understood wrongly. Then u can use foreach to enter each of nested result

Comment: @Çağrı u r copying my answer. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use load dash library to `cloneDeep` array
 https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep